# Group by in mongoDB with property construction

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, group-by, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection named Accounts like below data

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e93fea52f804ab99b54e4a2"),
    "account" : "first",
    "connect" : "Always",
    "desc" : "first account feature first phase",
    "status" : true
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e93fea32c804ab99b12e4d1"),
    "account" : "second",
    "connect" : "Sometimes",
    "desc" : "second account feature first phase",
    "status" : true
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e93fea52f804ab99b55a7b1"),
    "account" : "first",
    "connect" : "Sometimes",
    "desc" : "first account feature second phase",
    "status" : true
}
```

Trying to group and construct data in such a way that query should return a result like below structure

```
/* First Row */
    "account" : "first",
    [
    {
        _id:ObjectId("5e93fea52f804ab99b54e4a2") 
        "connect" : "Always",
        "desc" : "first account feature first phase",
        "status" : true
    },
    {
        _id:ObjectId("5e93fea52f804ab99b55a7b1") 
        "connect" : "Sometimes",
        "desc" : "first account feature second phase",
        "status" : true
    },

    ]

/* Second Row */
     "account" : "second",
    [
    {
        _id:ObjectId("5e93fea32c804ab99b12e4d1") 
        "connect" : "Always",
        "desc" : "second account feature first phase",
        "status" : true
    },

    ]
```

Looking to group with **Account** and the respective account Row should have other related data of that Id.

**What i tried**

I tried writing below query

```
db.accounts.aggregate(
    { 
        $match : {account : {$in: ["first", "second"]}}
    }
    ,
    { 
        $group : { 
             _id : "$account"
        }
    }
);
```

But this is working partially right returning list of accounts like first, second but not related properties.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `$group` use the `$push` accumulator to get the array of grouped data

```
db.accounts.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { account: { $in: ["first", "second"] } },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$account",
      data: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
    },
  }
]);
```

Comment: the above query works fine in RoboMongo, but when i try to add that to my node repository i get the below exception

Argument of type '{ $match: { account: { $in: any; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and '$match' does not exist in type 'any[]'.

Comment: It looks like you are using typescript? Pls show your full code

Comment: It is difficult to post the code in comment, so i have created a new question below

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61205171/argument-of-type-match-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-any-nodejs

Comment: i have just one more query, what if i want to change the data property to the type of account, like instead of data it should come first, second

i tried giving it the _id / "$account" but it doesn't work.

Comment: use another project stage. `{ $project: { account: "$_id", data: 1 }}`

Comment: that is constructing two properties like below "_id": "first", account: "first:. Rest nothing populating.

Comment: Also im trying to get result like first : {}, second: {} depending on the matched group value
but what I'm returning with is

{
    "_id" : "account",
    "data" : [ 
        {
        // data here
        }, 
        {
        // data here
        }, 
 
    ],
    "account" : "youtube"
}