# Argument of type 'match' is not assignable to parameter of type any[] - nodejs / mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, types

My query is running fine in RoboMongo, but when I construct the same in my nodeJs environment I'm getting the exception.

Below is my code

**Repository function**

```
public find = async (account: any): Promise<any> => {
  return PromoTypes.aggregate(
    {
      $match: { account: { $in: account } }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$account',
        data: {
          $push: { _id: '$_id', description: '$description', iteration: '$iteration' }
        }
      }
    }
  );
};
```

**Service file calling the above repo. function**

**AccountService.ts**

```
public accountService = async (accountid: string): Promise<any> => {
 //accounttypes is an array constructed to pass to the repo, it has more business logic about construction which I have not included in this code. But the object would be as below

 accounttypes = ["first,second"]
 let accountDetails = await AccountRepo.find(accounttypes);
}
```

Below is the error that I'm getting.

```
 Argument of type '{ $match: { account: { $in: any; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and '$match' does not exist in type 'any[]'.ts(2345)
```

**What I tried**

I tried changing the promise type to below types

```
 1. public accountService = async (accountid: string): Promise<any[]> =>{
 2. public accountService = async (accountid: string): Promise<Array<Object>> => {
 3. public accountService = async (accountid: string): Promise<Object> => {
```

None of the above approaches work for fixing the issue.

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html aggregate function need an array of objects

Comment: Wrap your aggregation query into `[...]`

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass an array to the `aggregate` pipeline

```
public find = async (account: any): Promise<any> => {
  return PromoTypes.aggregate([
    {
      $match: { account: { $in: account } }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$account',
        data: {
          $push: { _id: '$_id', description: '$description', iteration: '$iteration' }
        }
      }
    }
  ]);
};
```